Robot model going to the opposite direction in RVIZ when navigating
This only sometimes and my solution for this is to restart my robot state publisher or bring_up. Sometimes it it accurate and sometimes it is not. Attached is the video for this problem. Thanks!
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/o2jUrSe-OFA
